# USB over RDP transfer

Tags: windows, usb, printer, remote-desktop

I have an Olivetti PR2 plus printer connected to the local machine. This machine goes to the terminal via RDP. When printer connected via LPT and COM all works fine, the ports are forwared to the terminal. But when USB is used the port seems to be not forwared as printer doesn't work.

Can anybody suggest any free solutions to USB forwarding via RDP with this printer case? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A USB printer usually does redirect, on condition that the server has a matching driver and the port-name begins with "USBn".

If you have installed an Olivetti driver for the printer, try to use the Microsoft generic driver instead.

You can also try the hint from this Microsoft [article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q302361) :
Locate registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\AddIns\RDPDR`
add a new DWORD Value called `FilterQueueType` and give it a value of FFFFFFFF.

If there are bitness differences between server and client, one being 32-bit and the other 64-bit, then you need to install the matching printer driver manually on the server.